# UPDATE not working in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, authentication, android-sqlite

I have a login and reset password activity. When I enter the new updated password and try to login again, I cannot do so with the new password. Logging in with the old password works fine. Basically, the password field is not getting updated/overwritten.

There is no error in the logcat. Just that the password is not updated.

Please help as I am new to android development.

Code for update( DataRegister is the class with GET AND SET functions):

```
 public int updatePassword(DataRegister dataregister) {

  db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues updated = new ContentValues();
    updated.put("PASSWORD", dataregister.getPASSWORD());

 return db.update(DataRegister.TABLE, updated, "EMAIL=?" , new String[]{email});


}
```

Code for retrieval:

```
 public String getPass(DataRegister dataRegister) {

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(DataRegister.TABLE, null, "EMAIL=?",
            new String[]{dataRegister.getEMAIL()}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())

    {
        pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
    }
    return pass;


    // return contact


}
```

Code for Login:

```
 String email = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            dataRegister.setEMAIL(email);

            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            dataRegister.setPASSWORD(password);

            String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(dataRegister);

            Toast.makeText(Login.this, storedPassword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Boolean a=loginDataBaseAdapter.isExist(dataRegister.getEMAIL());
           validation = getSharedPreferences("myShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {

                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        "Congrats: Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            else {

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                            "User Name or Password does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }



        }
    });
```

Code for reset password:

```
public class ResetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em2);
    dataRegister=new DataRegister();

    loginDataBaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();



    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text12);
    conpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text13);

    email1 = email.getText().toString();
    dataRegister.setEMAIL(email1);
    pass1 = pass.getText().toString();

    conpass1 = conpass.getText().toString();
    dataRegister.setPASSWORD(conpass1);

    Button btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (pass1.equals(conpass1)) {

             loginDataBaseAdapter.updatePassword(email1,pass1);
                String newpass = loginDataBaseAdapter.getPass(dataRegister);



                Toast.makeText(ResetPassword.this, newpass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPassword.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                finish();

            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(ResetPassword.this,
                        "Password does not match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you for updating data :

```
  public void updating( Password password) {
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

        value.put( PasswordDAO.LOGIN, password.getlogin() );
        value.put( PasswordDAO.PASSWORD, password.getPassword());

        this.mDb.update( PasswordDAO.NAME_TABLE, value, PasswordDAO.ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(password.getId())} );
    }
```

PasswordDao is the name of the class who extends the DAOBase, NAME_TABLE is "Password", and you need to create a class password with id login and password.

hope this can help you

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand what PasswordDao class does. I have a DataRegister class which has all the fields GET and SET initialised and my Table name is DataRegister.TABLE. Database Adapter class has the sqlite CRUD functions. Can you please explain in these terms?

Comment: passwordDao is the class i'm using in activity like this :
   `public PasswordDAO passwordDab;`
  `passwordDab = new PasswordDAO(getBaseContext());`
and after you can use passwordDab.updating(pass)